# How to extract one 'column' of attributes from JSON

Tags: jquery, arrays, json

I have JSON data like this:

```
{ "krs_semester": [
   { "id_krs": "6723b92dd027470822d3914f8be178bd",
     "id_belanja": "0b38a133282251406979ba675b896ec5",
     "nimhs": "51016002",
     "kodesmt": "20182",
     "kodemk": "13000007",
     "sks": "2",
     "status": "1"
   },
   { "id_krs": "6723b92dd027470822d3914f8be178bd",
     "id_belanja": "6130bfc0ec155ff195ecc8dda6d0344c",
     "nimhs": "51016002",
     "kodesmt": "20182",
     "kodemk": "13000005",
     "sks": "2",
     "status": "1"
   },
   { "id_krs": "6723b92dd027470822d3914f8be178bd",
     "id_belanja": "a12f7877cdd71e79660534d898ffa027",
     "nimhs": "51016002",
     "kodesmt": "20182",
     "kodemk": "13000006",
     "sks": "2",
     "status": "1"
   }] 
}
```

and I did this to extract all `kodesmt` into an array

```
var kmk = [];
var idx=0
$.each(data.krs_semester, function(key, val){
  kmk[idx] = val.kodemk;
  idx++;
})
```

so, I've got this `kmk` array

```
["13000007", "13000005", "13000006"]
```

Is there any simpler and more efficient ways to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd use a [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function:

```
var kmk = data.krs_semester.map(function (c) {
  return c.kodemk;
});
```

Or in ES6:

```
var kmk = data.krs_semester.map(c => c.kodemk);
```

**Working Snippet**

```js
var data = { "krs_semester": [
   { "id_krs": "6723b92dd027470822d3914f8be178bd",
     "id_belanja": "0b38a133282251406979ba675b896ec5",
     "nimhs": "51016002",
     "kodesmt": "20182",
     "kodemk": "13000007",
     "sks": "2",
     "status": "1"
   },
   { "id_krs": "6723b92dd027470822d3914f8be178bd",
     "id_belanja": "6130bfc0ec155ff195ecc8dda6d0344c",
     "nimhs": "51016002",
     "kodesmt": "20182",
     "kodemk": "13000005",
     "sks": "2",
     "status": "1"
   },
   { "id_krs": "6723b92dd027470822d3914f8be178bd",
     "id_belanja": "a12f7877cdd71e79660534d898ffa027",
     "nimhs": "51016002",
     "kodesmt": "20182",
     "kodemk": "13000006",
     "sks": "2",
     "status": "1"
   }] 
};
var kmk = data.krs_semester.map(function (c) {
  return c.kodemk;
});
console.log(kmk);
```

Comment: Thank You for the fast and very cool response, @PraveenKumarPurushothaman